# Postfix block IP via restrictions and iptables do not block spammer IP

Tags: iptables, postfix-mta

It seems like I get lots of connection attempts from Russia which tries to reach my Postfix server. Now I'm trying to block this IP address on Postfix side and via iptables.

Here is the log entry:

```
Jul 21 16:31:46 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3347]: warning: unknown[193.35.48.18]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Jul 21 16:31:46 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3349]: warning: unknown[193.35.48.18]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Jul 21 16:31:46 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3347]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[193.35.48.18]
Jul 21 16:31:46 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3347]: disconnect from unknown[193.35.48.18] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
Jul 21 16:31:46 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3349]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[193.35.48.18]
Jul 21 16:31:46 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3349]: disconnect from unknown[193.35.48.18] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
Jul 21 16:31:46 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3347]: connect from unknown[193.35.48.18]
Jul 21 16:31:46 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3349]: connect from unknown[193.35.48.18]
Jul 21 16:31:48 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3347]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[193.35.48.18]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Jul 21 16:31:48 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3349]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[193.35.48.18]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Jul 21 16:31:54 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3349]: warning: unknown[193.35.48.18]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Jul 21 16:31:54 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3347]: warning: unknown[193.35.48.18]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Jul 21 16:31:54 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3349]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[193.35.48.18]
Jul 21 16:31:54 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3347]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[193.35.48.18]
Jul 21 16:31:54 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3349]: disconnect from unknown[193.35.48.18] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
Jul 21 16:31:54 netcup postfix/smtps/smtpd[3347]: disconnect from unknown[193.35.48.18] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
```

Iptables rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             my.domain.com        icmp echo-request ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  193.35.48.18         anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Restrictions in Postfix main.cf:

```
# HELO restrictions:
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit

# Sender restrictions:
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit
# Client restrictions
smtpd_client_restrictions =
  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_checks,
  permit

# Recipient restrictions:
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,
   reject_invalid_hostname,
   reject_unauth_pipelining,
   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
   reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf,
   reject_rhsbl_client blackhole.securitysage.com,
   reject_rhsbl_sender blackhole.securitysage.com,
   reject_rbl_client relays.ordb.org,
   reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl,
   reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
   reject_rbl_client proxies.blackholes.wirehub.net,
   reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
   reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
   reject_rbl_client opm.blitzed.org,
   reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,
   reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
   reject_rbl_client multihop.dsbl.org,
   reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
   permit_mynetworks,
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   permit
```

The client_checks file content:

```
193.35.48.18    REJECT Your IP is spam
```

All the rules do not prevent that IP address from accessing Postfix. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fail2ban.
I bet you will be surprised. I did try it on centos 7, and it worked well.

- Install **fail2ban** package in your server
- start and enable the service
- copy jail.conf to jail.local
- set the bantime and findtime to your preference.
- activate/enable the service (postfix-sasl, postfix, postfix-rbl, sshd
  ) you want fail2ban work with.
  and done.

you can visit this [site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos-7) or [this](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-fail2ban-on-centos-7/) site if you are running on centos7 or for debain this [link](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/install-fail2ban-debian/) or you can google and visit site which best meets your requirement installing fail2ban